# Can we add the synonym [brine] for [brining]?

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

There are 26 [brining](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brining) questions (and it has a brief tag wiki statement), and [brine](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brine) only has ten questions. I don't even have the rep to propose the synonym, so could a mod help out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for noticing. I merged the two tags.

Comment: Did you add a synonym?

Comment: @Aaronut I don't see it listed, but I do see a proposal to make brining a synonym for brining... maybe it was proposed on brine then merged in? I didn't know you could synonymize a tag to itself!

Comment: @jefromi that was me. I proposed the synonym first, noticed the merge tool later and used it. Didn't know that the synonym will stay, this time pointing to itself.

Comment: Yeah, that actually messed up the synonym. I had to delete the pending one and create a new one. Merging doesn't create a tag synonym, unless you use the merge option when you create one (using the moderator tools, not 10k tools). Just FYI.